# How to convert List object to string in java

Tags: java, string

How do I get the string value from below snippet:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list1= (List<Map<String, Object>>) mymap.get("getProduct");
Map<String, Object> myList= list1.get(0);
List<String> myproduct=  (List<String>) myList.get("productName");
System.out.println("value " +myproduct.toString());
```

When I try to print this I'm always getting as an object instead of plain string.
My Output:

```
[Apple]
```

Expected output:

```
Apple
```

I'm very new to Java, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What if `myproduct` contains more than one element? Or no elements? How would you want the output to look?

Comment: I Just need first element

Comment: Then you need to grab the first element: `myproduct.get(0)`. That will fail with an exception, however, if the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Because `myproduct` is `List` with string values, for example below is list with fruit names

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add("apple");
  list.add("mango");
System.out.println(fruits);   //[apple,mango]
```

If you want each value from list you can simply iterate using `for each` loop

```
for(String str : myproduct) {
    System.out.println(str);
   }
```

If you just need first element you can get by index, but might end up with index out of bound exception if list is empty

```
String ele = myproduct.get(0);
```

or by using java-8 stream

```
String ele = myproduct.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```